# Trying understand the feed importer

Tags: commerce, importing-exporting

I inherited this website that has this product feed importer for my commerce store the products load correct but the category hierarchy_category is not being assigned in the content display field. I am trying to under "Search Taxonomy terms by: There are three selects.
my csv feed has Hierarchy_Category column that is map product category.
My Hierarchy_Category are numbers but the search is set to term name. Do I need to change to Term ID

[image]

Comment: yes it needs to be tid. what you can do is install feeds_tamper and there might be an option to convert the taxonomy name to a tid during processing. Otherwise you'll have to fix up your feed data and find/replace the taxonomy name with the proper tid that you need to look up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have term name in your product sheet then keep it as term name otherwise change it to the tid if you have term-id. (Make sure that you entered exact term name which is stored in database).

Feeds module automatically detects it.